# How to make a tkinter window that will stop updating it self after getting destroyed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a camera with `opencv` and `tkinter` in Python. I have a little issue with the code the when closing the window. I have to update window regularly because the webcam is taking pictures regularly and showing in the window as a video. So I have a while loop and made the condition True but it runs even after the window is closed so it raises a error. I have tried it many items by different methods but it shows the same error. Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root1 = Tk()

root = Toplevel()
root.title("Camera v1.0")
root.configure(bg = 'black')


label = Label(root, text= "Camera v1.0",font = ("times new roman","15","bold"),bg = "black",fg = 'goldenrod2')
label.pack(side = TOP,fill = BOTH)

frame = Frame(root,bg = 'black')
frame.pack()


label2 = Label(frame,bg = 'red')
label2.pack()

btn_verify = Button(frame,text = "Take a Snapshot", font = ("times new roman","11","bold"),activebackground ='red',bg = "#bf80ff",fg="#000080",width = 15)
btn_verify.pack(side = BOTTOM,expand = False)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    if cap:
        img = cap.read()[1]
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(img))
        label2['image'] = img 
        root.update()
    else:
        pass

root.mainloop()
```

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "c:\Users\swach\OneDrive\Swachchha\পাইথন দিয়ে
 মজা\Opencv_Projects\face_recognizing.py", line 49, in <module>
     img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(img))   File "D:\Python Interpreter\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 112, in
 __init__
     self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)   File "D:\Python Interpreter\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4064, in __init__
     Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)   File "D:\Python Interpreter\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3997, in
 __init__
     master = _get_default_root('create image')   File "D:\Python Interpreter\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 297, in _get_default_root
     raise RuntimeError(f"Too early to {what}: no default root window") RuntimeError: Too early to create image: no default root window
```

Is there any updating method which will not update tkinter window after being destroyed in tkinter?

Comment: Instead of a `while True` loop try using a `.after` script

Comment: How? Can you write me the code???? -TheLizzard

Comment: I mean only the after method? PLS TELL ELLABOLATELY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def refresh_image_loop():
    if cap:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(img))
        label2["image"] = tk_img
        label2.tk_img = tk_img
        root.after(100, refresh_image_loop) # After 100 ms run `refresh_image` again
    else:
        pass

root1 = Tk()

root = Toplevel()
root.title("Camera v1.0")
root.configure(bg="black")

label = Label(root, text="Camera v1.0", font=("times new roman", "15", "bold"),bg="black", fg="goldenrod2")
label.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

frame = Frame(root, bg="black")
frame.pack()

label2 = Label(frame, bg="red")
label2.pack()

btn_verify = Button(frame,text = "Take a Snapshot", font=("times new roman", "11", "bold"), activebackground='red', bg="#bf80ff", fg="#000080", width=15)
btn_verify.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=False)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

refresh_image_loop()
root.mainloop()
```

It uses a `.after` loop. When the window is closed it will automatically cancel the next `.after` script. The `.after` script tells `tkinter` to call `refresh_image_loop` after 100 ms which is 0.1 sec.

Comment: You need to keep a reference of the image inside `refresh_image_loop()`, otherwise the image will not be shown due to garbage collection.

Comment: @acw1668 I forgot about that. Thanks for the suggestion, fixed the answer. Also next time feel free to edit my answer :D